# Can Pandas read a nested JSON blob without parsing sub JSON structures?

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to parse a JSON blob with Pandas without parsing the nested JSON structures. Here's an example of what I mean.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

x = json.loads('{"test":"something", "yes":{"nest":10}}')
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
```

When I do `df.head()` I get the following:

```
        test         yes
nest    something    10
```

What I really want is ...

```
        test         yes
1       something    {"nest": 10}
```

Any ideas on how to do this with Pandas? I have workaround ideas, but I'm parsing GBs of JSON files and do not want to be dependent on a slow `for` loop to convert and prep the information for Pandas. It would be great to do this efficiently while still utilizing the speed of Pandas.

Note: There's been a correction to this question to fix and an error about my reference to json objects.

Comment: That's not a JSON blob or structure, it's just a plain Python dict. So it sounds like you've already parsed the JSON into native Python objects somewhere else, which means you're probably _already_ doing exactly what you didn't want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I skipped a step about the converting the json to dictionary. I have edited the question above to reflect that.

Comment: Now I don't even understand what you're hoping to accomplish. If you're not trying to utilize the speed of Pandas for JSON parsing as you initially said, what are you trying to accomplish? If you time things, I'm willing to bet the cost of that `json.parse` is an order of magnitude higher than the cost of a simple rearrangement of the structure using, e.g., a dict comprehension. If it isn't, show us how you're doing it, show where it's slow, verify that it really is a hotspot worth optimizing, and ask how to optimize it.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to parse a JSON blob with Pandas

No you're not. You're just constructing a `DataFrame` out of a plain old Python `dict`. That `dict` might have been parsed from JSON somewhere else in your code, or it may never have been JSON in the first place. It doesn't matter; either way, you're not using Pandas's JSON parsing. In fact, if you did try to construct a `DataFrame` directly out of a JSON string, you would get a `PandasError`.

If you *do* use Pandas parsing, you can use its options, as documented in [`pandas.read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.read_json.html). For example:

```
>>> j = '{"test": "something", "yes": {"nest": 10}}'
>>> pd.read_json(j, typ='series')
test        something
yes     {u'nest': 10}
dtype: object
```

(Of course that's obviously a `Series`, not a `DataFrame`. But I'm not sure exactly what you want your `DataFrame` to be here…)

But if you've already parsed the JSON elsewhere, you obviously can't use Pandas's data parsing on it.

---

Also:

> … and do not want to be dependent on a slow for loop to convert and prep the information for Pandas …

Then use, e.g., a dict comprehension, generator expression, `itertools` function, or something else that can do the looping in C instead of in Python.

However, I doubt that the speed of looping over the JSON strings is actually a real performance issue here, compared to the cost of parsing the JSON, building the Pandas structures, etc. Figure out what's actually taking the time by profiling, then optimize that, instead of just picking some random part of your code and hoping it makes a difference.